# MLCP copy could only copy partial data from a 3 node cluster

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I have a most basic 3-node cluster ML environment.
I need to copy the data down to other ML environment with MLCP copy command.

However, it seems it could copy about 1/3 of the documents down only.

[image: MLCP Copy Summary]

**I have no clue about what is wrong.** Below is the error message in the mlcp copy process.

For me, it is strange why all 3 nodes IP addresses appear, as I only specify one node address only in the mlcp **input_host** parameter. How the MLCP knows all other hosts' IP?

It seems the error is related to the replica forest. However, in ML admin UI, all forests including those replicas are normal. Anyway, it is just a copy; I thought it should have nothing to do with replica DB.

```
 [Session: user=UserABC, cb=#288039430218036231 [ContentSource: user=UserABC, cb=XYC-content [provider: address=10.111.10.123/10.111.10.123:9001, pool=0/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/10.0-6.2, Server: XDBC/9.0-9.1]
2022-09-03 17:25:34 ERROR DatabaseContentReader:286 - QueryException:com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest XYC-content-3-replica-1 not available: sync replicating
 [Session: user=UserABC, cb=#3880528255788069631 [ContentSource: user=UserABC, cb=XYC-content [provider: address=/10.111.10.121:9001, pool=0/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/10.0-6.2, Server: XDBC/9.0-9.1]
2022-09-03 17:25:34 ERROR LocalJobRunner:348 - Error running task:
2022-09-03 17:25:34 ERROR LocalJobRunner:349 - com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest XYC-content-3-replica-1 not available: sync replicating
 [Session: user=UserABC, cb=#3880528255788069631 [ContentSource: user=UserABC, cb=XYC-content [provider: address=/10.111.10.121:9001, pool=0/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/10.0-6.2, Server: XDBC/9.0-9.1]
2022-09-03 17:25:46 ERROR DatabaseContentReader:286 - QueryException:com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest XYC-content-1-replica-1 not available: sync replicating
 [Session: user=UserABC, cb=#9762515839579968807 [ContentSource: user=UserABC, cb=XYC-content [provider: address=/10.111.10.122:9001, pool=0/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/10.0-6.2, Server: XDBC/9.0-9.1]
2022-09-03 17:25:46 ERROR LocalJobRunner:348 - Error running task:
2022-09-03 17:25:46 ERROR LocalJobRunner:349 - com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest XYC-content-1-replica-1 not available: sync replicating
 [Session: user=UserABC, cb=#9762515839579968807 [ContentSource: user=UserABC, cb=XYC-content [provider: address=/10.111.10.122:9001, pool=0/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/10.0-6.2, Server: XDBC/9.0-9.1]
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you apply the `restrict_hosts` option, after initially connecting, MLCP will discover the hosts and forest topology, then connect and send data directly to the D-node hosting the forest where the content lives. What is the assignment policy for the DB? If it is Segment, consider changing to Bucket. There are open bugs and issues with Segment assignment policy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using load balancer?
If yes, make sure to enable sticky sessions.

Comment: I am pointing to node 1 directly without using a load balancer.  

Somehow I could never make the F5 load balancer work. I could not find out where to specify the sticky sessions or how to configure the persistence profile with it.  In contrast, the load balancer from ML azure cluster image works well.